# Android IndexableList with section doesnt scroll after i move out of section header

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have A IndexedList which shows index on the right which i implemented using the below link:

[IndexableListView](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView)

Now in the Indexed view i have Sections for each Alphabet. The issue which i am facing is when i start scrolling from a section header (it should not scroll the list) but when i reach to end of header the list should start scrolling , which isnt happening. Meaning **if i start scrolling from header the list never scrolls**. I am referring to the below SectionedAdapter for this:

[sectionedAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter). This is the simplest Section Adapter available for Android's ListView.

Comment: Thanks Artyom just wanted to know how do we make sure that as soon as i move out of the sectionheader the scroll should work fine.